# How to read large volume of parquet data in databricks

Tags: python, azure, optimization, databricks, parquet

I have over 100k Parquet files in Azure Data Lake and have a mount point as well. I need to read all the files and load them into a dataframe. In total, I have around 3 billion records, and not all files have all the columns; the column order and data types may vary. I've tried merge schema, inferring schema, and using a custom schema with all columns as string data type, but nothing is working. Finally, I decided to read all the files into a list and then iterate through them one by one. Is this approach acceptable, or is there a better solution available?

**Try 1**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from functools import reduce

schema = StructType([
StructField("COL1", StringType(), nullable=True),
StructField("COL2", StringType(), nullable=True),
StructField("COL3", StringType(), nullable=True),
StructField("COL4", StringType(), nullable=True)
])
files = [file.path for file in dbutils.fs.ls("datalake_path_here")]

dfs = []
def load_data(file_path):
return spark.read.format("parquet").schema(schema).load(file_path)

for file_path in files:
  df = load_data(file_path)
  dfs.append(df)
  final_df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.union(df2), dfs)
```

Error : OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceed

**Try 2**

```
spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("/path/to/parquet/files")
```

Error : CANNOT_MERGE_SCHEMA] failed merging schemas:
Schema that cannot be merged with the initial schema

**Try 3**

```
for file_path in files:
      df = spark.read.format("parquet").schema(schema).load(file_path)
      df_final.union(df)
```

It's executed successfully, but it took 4 hours. After this step, i have to insert into table.